# How can I change the color of wedges in a rose diagram in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rose-plot

I have a rose diagram (code below) that I plotted in ggplot but I can't figure out how to change the color of the wedges. No matter what I try they remain black. This is the first time I have ever used ggplot so it may be something very simple.

Thanks!

```
rose <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Degrees))+
  stat_bin(breaks = (0:8 - 0.5)/8 * 360, color='white') +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 0:7/8*360,
    labels = c("N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW")
  ) +
  coord_polar(start=-pi/8)
rose
```

Comment: Have you tried using `fill`?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `fill` aesthetic.  `color` controls the color of lines and points.  When considering shapes and polygons, `color` controls the *outer line of the shape*.  The aesthetic `fill` controls the color *inside the shape*.  Here's a clear example:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(degrees = sample(1:360, 1000, replace=TRUE))

ggplot(df, aes(x=degrees)) +
  stat_bin(breaks=(0:8 - 0.5)/8 * 360, color='red', fill='skyblue') +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks=0:7/8*360,
    labels=c('N','NE','E','SE','S','SW','W','NW')
  ) +
  coord_polar(start=-pi/8)
```

Note that the line outside is red and the shapes themselves are skyblue.

[image]

Comment: Thank You! I really appreciate the help.